# How to prove third party review and ratings to be correct and real?

Tags: schema.org, structured-data, json-ld

We are developing an App which of course has a website.
I added some of our ratings and reviews from the users given in Google Play and Apple Store and corresponding JSON-LD's.

I could not find the answers from the Internet where is more information about faking the data. E.g. making your rating 5/5 from 1000000 people. I wouldn't want to fake this so a few questions arose:

It is the developer of the site who can add the data which can be fake or real.

Code:

```
    "@context": "https://schema.org",
"@graph": [
    {
        "@type": "UserReview",
        "name": "App store reviews",
        "itemReviewed": {
            "@type": "Thing",
            "@id": "https://habinator.com",
            "name": "Habinator App"
        },
        "datePublished": "2019-08-01",
        "reviewRating": {
            "@type": "AggregateRating",
            "ratingValue": "4.9",
            "ratingCount": "27",
            "bestRating": "5",
            "worstRating": "1"
        }
    }
```

The question is: How can I prove the authenticity of a user review? Linking to the third party site where the review exists? Any other means? In both stores, there is a "Link to this review" link. Is it be possible to link the individual Rating to this link?